# Cross Origin Request Blocked

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, cors

My Gis Client Program, using OpenLayers, and my GeoServer were running on the same server, everything worked fine.

Now, I started a new instance of My Gis Client Program on another server. There, I get the following Problem:

WMS Layers work fine, but for the WFS Layer I get: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://mygeoserver/mylayerr. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

What can I do about that?

Comment: Well, you could move the resource or enable CORS. CORS seems like the right answer, and there is a previous answer for this for openlayers http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71715/enabling-cors-in-openlayers. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: As an alternative you need to go through a proxy (beware of the implications) to be installed on the same domain of GeoServer.

Comment: The Problem is for me only the WFS Layer, the WMS works perfectly. If I add `tileOptions: {crossOriginKeyword: 'anonymous'},
    transitionEffect: null`, to the Layer Object, it does not change anything.

Comment: You need to enable CORS on the server with the layers. Adding anything to JS on the client side cannot solve the problem. If you cannot adjust CORS settings of the server, just use a proxy (written e.g. in PHP) to proccess your requests.

Comment: @MichalZimmermann and how can we do it on the server alone?